# Changing complexity from O(n) to o(logn)

Tags: java, data-structures

We have a linkedlist called `ratings` that contains 3 integers 
userId, ItemId and value of the actual rating (example from 0 to 10)
this method actually returns rating of **User i and item j** that the programs reads it from a **File** and returns -1 if there is no rating

the method that is BigOh(n) :

```
public int getRating(int i, int j){
    ratings.findFirst();
    while(!ratings.empty()){
        if(ratings.retrieve().getUserId() == i && ratings.retrieve().getItemId() == j)
            return ratings.retrieve().getValue();
        else 
            ratings.findNext();
    }
    return -1;  
}
```

How can I do this in BigOh(logn)?
Or is there anyway I can solve it using Binary Search tree?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you reading from a file or a linked list?

Comment: I think the answer depends on how you are creating your file, and the assumptions you make from that. For example, if it's sorted, you could probably use a BST. However, you may still endup having to read the entire file, or storing the entire file in memory.

Comment: Are you able to load contents of the file into memory and use a more efficient data structure like a hash table or something?

Comment: i forgot to say that i store the file in a linkedlist

Comment: Have a look for skip lists. A pure linked list cannot do log(n) search.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:  use a different data structure.  Linked lists aren't capable of doing searches in anything *other* than linear time, since each element is linked together without any real semblance or order (and even *if* the list were sorted, you'd still have to do *some* kind of timed traversal).

One data structure that you could use would be a [`Table`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table) from Guava.  With this data structure, you'd have to do more work to *add* an element in...

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Rating> ratings = HashBasedTable.create();
ratings.put(rating.getUserId(), rating.getItemId(), rating);
```

...but you can retrieve *very* quickly - in roughly O(1) time since `HashBasedTable` is backed by `LinkedHashSet<Integer, LinkedHashSet<Integer, Rating>>`.

```
ratings.get(i, j);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hashing to achieve your task in **O(1)**. Please read this [article](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Hashing/hashing.html) to gain a deeper understanding about hashing.

Since you are using Java, you can use [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to accomplish your task. Note that, worst case time complexity for `hashing` technique is **O(log n)** but on average it is **O(1)**. If you are more interested to know about hash tables and amortized analysis, please go through this [article](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec20.html).

**Code Example**: You can create a `Class` with the required attributes and implement `equals` and `hashCode` method as follows. [read [Java collections - hashCode() and equals()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html)]

```
class Rating {

    public int user_id; // id of the user who rated
    public int item_id; // id of the item being rated

    public Rating(int user_id, int item_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Rating)) {
            return false;
        }
        Rating ratingObj = (Rating) o;
        return ratingObj.user_id == user_id
                && ratingObj.item_id == item_id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + user_id;
        result = 31 * result + item_id;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then store values in `HashMap` as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Rating, Integer> ratingMap = new HashMap<>();
    Rating rt = new Rating(1, 5); // user id = 1, item id = 5
    ratingMap.put(rt, 3);
    rt = new Rating(1, 2); // user id = 1, item id = 2
    ratingMap.put(rt, 4);
    rt = new Rating(1, 3); // user id = 1, item id = 3
    ratingMap.put(rt, 5);

    // now search in HashMap
    System.out.println(ratingMap.get(new Rating(1, 3))); // prints 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As presented, this could hardly be done in O(log n). You're looking through elements until you find the one you need. In the worst case, you won't find the element you want until the end of the loop, thus making it O(n).

Of course, if `ratings` were a dictionary you'd retrieve the value in almost O(1): user ids as keys and for example a list of ratings as value. Insertion would be a bit slower but not much.

Comment: In short, the linked list is probably a bad structure for what you're trying to do